# How to write a complex master-detail query in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, join

I need some help getting a SQL query running the way I need. I know you sql gurus will be laughing at this, but I really don't know how to do this :-(
I have two tables in a MS-SQL database. One is **workers**, the other is **contracts**. They are in a 1-to-many relationship, that is one worker can have zero or more contracts.
There was a change in the contract and all the workers were requested to sign new contracts.
What I need to get is all the workers who HAVE NOT yet signed a new contract. That is who do not have a contract after a certain date. I tried using left outer join, but it didn't work :-(

These are the key columns in the tables:

**Workers:**
WorkerID
FirstName
LastName
...

**Contracts:**
ContractID
Date
WorkerID
Amount
...

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Trex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select w.WorkerID, w.Firstname, w.LastName
from Workers w
left outer join Contracts c on w.WorkerID = c.WorkerID
    and c.Date > @MyDate
where c.WorkerID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query:

```
select * from Workers where WorkerID not in
(select distinct WorkerID from Contracts where Date > @myDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking with a sub query but including the date:

```
SELECT * from Workers where WorkerID not in
(SELECT DISTINCT WorkerID FROM CONTRACTS WHERE Date > @MyDate)
```

where @MyDate is your certain date after which the contracts changed.

Comment: I see that.  But I didn't see the edit until after I posted mine.